# SPRoleType.None Problem

Tags: roles

I want to set the SPRoleType.None to a page for a user but I have a problem using
roleDef = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.None);

I understand that for None and Guest this can't be done that way.

How can I achive this ?

TIA